# truncate string from the first letter before the first point?

Tags: c#, string, truncate

I have a list of strings. They look like: 
`this.is.the.first.one`
`that.is.the.second`
`thishasnopoint` 
Some of them have points, but some of them don't have points. I only need truncate the strings from its first letter before the possible first point using c#. The truncated strings should like as follows:
`this`
`that`
`thishasnopoint` 
Google searches don't show me any useful clues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple method is this:

```
string firstBit = wholeString.Split('.')[0];
```

`Split` turns it into an array of strings, separated on the `'.'` character. In the case of `thishasnopoint`, the array only has one element.

Comment: Slick..., and for those strings that don't have a period will always have the entire line in the zero position of the array returned ... Cool...

Answer (score 1):

Now I understood it right, The string is only of one those sequences... so this would do it:

```
var result = strings.Split('.').First();
```

---

If the string was: `this.is.the.first.one that.is.the.second thishasnopoint` - one string this:

```
var firstWords = new List<string>();
strings.Split(' ').ForEach(x => firstWords.Add(x.Split('.').First()));
```

would return:

`List<string>` with three strings - `this that thishasnopoint`

Answer (score 1):

```
string getTruncated(string s) {
    int startIdx = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i) {
        if (Char.IsLetter(s[i])) {
            startIdx = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    int endIdx = s.IndexOf('.');
    if (startIdx != -1) {
        if (endIdx != -1) {
            return s.Substring(startIdx, endIdx);
        } else {
            return s.Substring(startIdx);
        }
    } else {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Works faster instead of "split" method, but it is more complex.

Comment: How is split implemented internally? What makes this faster?

Comment: Er ... why assume this is that performance sensitive? Your code is massively less maintainable than the versions that use Split. Also, if you are given a string like 111.234, which the OP doesn't preclude, your code would result in an ArgumentException.

Comment: Hammerstein, split method creates array of Strings, for example for input == "this.is.first.phrase" the split('.') will return String[] {"this", "is", "first", "phrase"} array, in which only zero'st element is being used, but other are to be GC.
David M, as the creater of post said, the result must be substring between first letter and first point. Then if input is only of digits, the exception is thrown.